# How to attach .ics to email?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I need to attach Outlook calendar file (.ics) to the email with `mail` function.

This is what I have now, but it is not working.

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$companyname = $_POST["company"];

$file = "webinar-041016.ics";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$EmailTo = "mail@mail.com";
$Subject = "New  Webinar Registration";

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Firstname: ";
$Body .= $firstname;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Lastname: ";
$Body .= $lastname;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Company Name: ";
$Body .= $companyname;
$Body .= "\n";

$headers = 'From: mail@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: mail@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$conf_subject = "Registration Complete ...";

$conf_body = "Dear " . $firstname . ",\n\nThank you..." ;
$conf_body .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; name=\"".$file."\"\r\n" ;
$conf_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
$conf_body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\"\r\n\r\n";
$conf_body.= $content."\r\n\r\n";

$conf_headers = 'From: web@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: web@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);
$conf_mail = mail($email, $conf_subject, $conf_body, $conf_headers);
// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "invalid";
}
//Attached is an Outlook calendar invite so that you can plan your day accordingly.\n\n 
?>
```

What should I do here? Is my encoding wrong?

Comment: Your script is open to injection attack, your MIME structure doesn't even exist, there are tons of opportunities for invalid encoding. You'd find it much easier if you [use PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), like you tagged your question with. In the current version there's even an ICS builder class bundled.

Comment: I need the solution with mail option..

Comment: Why? PHPMailer uses `mail()` by default, but your problem is not in calling `mail`, it's in building a valid message to pass to it, and that is not in the least bit simple.

Comment: That is one of the rules I was given to. "No external scripts". I understand .ics file might be particularly difficult to add as attachment. Do you know how to do it with `mail()`? If so, please post an answer.. Thanks.

Comment: Is someone *teaching* you to code like this?? ICS is pretty simple. You're not going to to do this safely and validly in less than a couple of thousand lines of code, and it's reinventing the wheel. SO isn't a place to get your code written for you, *especially* if you're meant to be figuring out yourself. You need to read and understand the docs on [email](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) and [MIME](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045). No it's not simple, but that's what you're asking for when you say "no external scripts". You can find code examples, but most will be wrong or unsafe.

Comment: No one is teaching me, it is a "rule". And I am not expecting anyone in SO to write a code for me from the scratch. Thanks.

Comment: That's a pointless, wasteful rule. Writing all the code from scratch is exactly what you asked for; The code you wrote is not much use as a starting point, and you demanded "I need the solution", which must be achieved without libraries. At the very least look at MIME structures of messages that are like what you want, get some vague idea of how it works, build your code to create that structure.

Comment: I never said I agree with the rule.. Agreed, wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already seen this:

[PHP Sending Mail](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php)

As a suggestion you might wanna have a look into [PHPMailer](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which narrows down the work you have to do, to a single line of code:

```
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');
```

Comment: Calendar emails are not quite like regular attachments - they are 3-way multipart/alternative structures. Fortunately PHPMailer has built in support for that - look at the `Ical` property.

Comment: But you can still send them as a file, it doesn't have to be interpreted as a multipart/alternative structure.

Comment: Officially it generally does, however in practice it's even more complicated. See [this bug](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175) and [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505024).